# How to solve a respawn problem for a character in FPS view?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this script that respawns my character at the coordinate of the cube when I press the R key. It works, but as soon as I release the key, the character returns to where he was before.
This script works on a character in the third person but not in view at first. So I think there must be some element in the basic script of the FPS view that prevents to work, but I can not find which one, and I'm novice at Unity so it's difficult to identify what all the functions are for.
I do not know if I can post the character code in FPS view as it is quite long, otherwise it can be found on asset store.

```
{
    public Transform spawnPoint;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
        {

            player.transform.position = spawnPoint.position;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You have some code somewhere that sets the position somewhere else, maybe in the update function of another script. 
What you are now providing is not sufficient to receive any form of help. It seems to me that you might want to start with one of the basic Unity tutorials and make sure that you understand those before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

This script is not the problem. Check the rest of scripts where you update the position. I guess you are assigning a vector saved on another script when you move the player.
Maybe with more info about other scripts I could be more accurate in the answer.

Comment: I think it's too complicated at the moment for me, I'll continue the rest and I'll come back to this problem when I have more knowledge. Thanks anyway for trying to help me.